# DateTimeOffset with JPA (hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, datetimeoffset

I have a JPA using Hibernate connected to SQLserver. It works but i have an exception each time i use entity with DateTimeOffset fields.

I tried with a custom type and used it like this:

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "EffectiveDate")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="DateTimeOffsetType")
private Serializable effectiveDate;
```

DateTimeOffsetType is my custom type I made like here:
[datetimeoffset hibernate mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733844/datetimeoffset-hibernate-mapping)

But still, it don't works. How can I be able to read DateTimeOffset with hibernate and JPA?

Comment: I tried with EclipseLink, and always the same error : DateTimeOffset cannot be converted to BINARY...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally resolved it by changing all the Serializable type of the fields in generated entities by TimeStamp types.