# ExecuteSQL doesn't select table if it having dateTime Offset value?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I have created table with single column having data type -dateTimeOffset value and inserted some values.

```
create table dto (dto datetimeoffset(7))
insert into dto values (GETDATE()) -- inserts date and time with 0 offset
insert into dto values (SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()) -- current date time and offset
insert into dto values ('20131114 08:54:00 +10:00') -- manual way
```

In Nifi,i have specified **"Select * from dto"** query in Execute SQL .

It shows below error..,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: createSchema: Unknown SQL type -155 cannot be converted to Avro type
```

If i change that column into dateTime then ExecuteSQL runs correctly but it doesn't worked in DateTimeOffset column.

Any help appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

datetimeoffset is a [MSSQL-specific JDBC type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733844/datetimeoffset-hibernate-mapping) and is not supported by ExecuteSQL (which supports the [standard JDBC types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.BIT)). You could try to cast the datetimeoffset field into some other standard type such as datetime, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953903/how-can-i-convert-a-sql-server-2008-datetimeoffset-to-a-datetime).

Comment: Thanks Mattyb for your response

Answer (score 1):

I've created a Custom Processor and adapted the JdbcCommon.java class to include SQL Server's DATETIMEOFFSET. It's just one line of code. I'll try to see if I can ask them to merge this on the official repo.

This is a piece of my JdbcCommon.java:

```java
                case TIMESTAMP:
                case TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE:
                case -101: // Oracle's TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
                case -102: // Oracle's TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE
                case -155: // SQL Server's DATETIMEOFFSET <---- added this line
                    addNullableField(builder, columnName,
                            u -> options.useLogicalTypes
                                    ? u.type(LogicalTypes.timestampMillis().addToSchema(SchemaBuilder.builder().longType()))
                                    : u.stringType());
                    break;
```