# Unable to use OffsetDateTime as a query parameter using JPA Data/JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, offsetdatetime

I have an `Entity` **CustomEntity** with a data member **updateDate** of type `OffsetDateTime`.

I have defined a `Repository` for this `Entity` which has a simple method to retrieve list of records matching **updateDate** as

```
List<CustomEntity> findByUpdateDate(OffsetDateTime updateDate);
```

Now, when this method is called from **Controller/Service** bean, I can see no matching record is retrieved; however, when I execute the generated SQL in the DB, I can see matching rows available.

*I can retrieve the records based on other data members of the entity; its just an issue with `OffsetDateTime` and `LocalDateTime`*

I got to understand that `java.time` package support was not in **JPA 2.1**; however I am using **JPA 2.3.1**. Do I need to use `Converter`s (as suggested for [JPA 2.1](https://thorben-janssen.com/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/)?

Any help is much appreciable.

**EDIT :-**
Below is the code for Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SAMPLE_TABLE")
public class CustomEntity {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    
    @Column
    private OffsetDateTime updateDate;
    
    //Getters & Setters
}
```

I am using **Microsoft SQL Server** and the generated `SQL` query (*hibernate generated*) looks something like below

```
select sample0_.id as id1_10, sample0_.updateDate as update2_10 from sample_table sample0_ where sample0_.updateDate=?
```

binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [**2021-07-27T17:22:34.597Z**]

Comment: What database are you using and how does the generates SELECT looks like?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, I am using ```MS SQL Server```. Let me update the original question with the generated query.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, please check now

Comment: As I can see there is no offfset in the time part. Is this correct?

Comment: the offset has been converted to Zulu, the date has 'Z'

Comment: Can you try to search with a date time range? I would say it's a timezone issue with JDBC

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I can execute range search on ```LocalDateTime``` (not sure why exact match is not possible); but for ```OffsetDateTime``` even range is not working. I see its timezone issue, because when I pass the range as ```(startDate.minusDay(1), startDate.plusDay(1))```, I can see the record. 
When I tried setting Spring boot app time zone as same as DB timezone; still ```OffsetDateTime``` range/exact match is not possible

Comment: What's the data type of the column in the database?

Comment: its ```datetimeoffset(7)```

Comment: Can you change the column to datetime2 and try again? Becuase I think Hibernate has a problem with datetimeoffset

Comment: Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733844/datetimeoffset-hibernate-mapping

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I do not have control over the database schema, hence any DML is out of the picture

Comment: In that case you must follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733844/datetimeoffset-hibernate-mapping

Comment: but I am not facing any error as mentioned in the problem statement of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733844/datetimeoffset-hibernate-mapping. Is it still relevant for my case?

Comment: Yes becuase the handling of the datetimeoffset with hibernate seems to be not correct

Comment: @SimonMartinelli With few changes to the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733844/datetimeoffset-hibernate-mapping I am able to fetch the record with exact match or range for ```OffsetDateTime```. However still unable to do exact match for ```LocalDateTime``` (Range works). I will post my code as an answer. Thank you for your kind help mate.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli A new problem arises now with update. When I fetch a row, modify some attribute and save; it gives me an error ```org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)```